# SOAP WCF parameters in request

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap

I am new to WCF. I have been working on a self-hosted WCF API in C#. I am building this according to externally created design documentation. I have made a lot of progress with setting everything up, however I reached an issue. According to the documentation I have to make a SOAP call with the following structure:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetResource>Test</tem:GetResource>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have tried utilizing the WCF MessageContract in order to achieve this, however the closest I have been able to come to this looks like the following request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetResource>
        <QName>Test</QName>
      </tem:GetResource>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As requested by Peter Csala:
The code for the MessageContract:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperName = "GetResource")]
public class GetResource
{
    [DataMember(Name = "GetResource")]
    public string QName;
}
```

The code for the ServiceContract interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "GetResource")]
public interface IResourceProperty
{
    [OperationContract]
    Task<GetResourceResponse> GetResource(GetResource Qname);
}
```

The code in the Service class:

```
public async Task<GetResourceResponse> GetResource(GetResource Qname)
    {
        return new GetResourceResponse();
    }
```

And lastly the relevant part of my generated WSDL:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetResource">
 <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetResource"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:message name="GetResourceResponse">
 <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetResourceResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="GetResource">
  <wsdl:operation name="GetResource">
  <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/GetResource/GetResource" name="GetResource" message="tns:GetResource"/>
  <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/GetResource/GetResourceResponse" name="GetResourceResponse" message="tns:GetResourceResponse"/>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
```

How do i achieve the request as written in the documentation?

Comment: Do you have access to the SOAP service's `wsdl`?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at my question. I made a typo in the original question. Im working with an external design document, so there is no WSDL.

Comment: Then could you please share with us the code which generates the sub-optimal request envelope?

Comment: Updated the question with the code. Also added some parts of my WSDL

Comment: Have you tried this: `[DataMember, XmlText] public string QName;` You might also need to change the class `[MessageContract, XmlSerializerFormat] public class GetResource`

Comment: Tried it, but it is still expecting the same request as before

Comment: Then have you tried to get rid of the `GetResource` class and define the service like this: `[OperationContract] Task<GetResourceResponse> GetResource(string GetResource);`

Comment: You can consider using Custom Message Encoder: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder